# google search console crawling my site another page, not the index page

Tags: search, google-analytics, console, google-search-console

my website is live from one months. I have linked it with google analytics code and google search console. The problem is when am searching for my site name 'MustuGo' it's showing another pages link not index page. I already submitted http://www.mustugo.com/index.php in google search console in Fetch as Google. Am not getting why google crawl is not updating and not crawling index.php page.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about search ranking and isn't programing related probably better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Google ranks its results on tons of factors. Ultimately what it boils down to is how relevant is a particular web page to the search term.

I am guessing the reason for your problem is that you have not mentioned the word "MustuGo" in your home page. If you have the word, preferably in heading tags and meta-data, then that will make Google think that your home page is most relevant to the search term "MustuGo".

Same applies for most of the search engines.